# Creating a PHP Class won't allow me to use control statements

Tags: php, class, if-statement, aptana

I have a pretty simple question so it seems. I am creating a class, in which I have a public function that takes an input. Inside of the function, I want to use and if statement to determine if the value is larger or smaller than a class property. When I begin to type the IF statement in my IDE (Aptana) it gives me a syntax error. I am new at PHP, so if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Aptana *wrongly* shows a syntax error in this situation. Once I entered a complete `if` statement, the syntax error went away.

Normally Aptana autofills (or at least tries to), but for some reason, it doesn't do that inside of the class object. Weird.

Comment: don't post if there is not answer, edit your question

Comment: I posted an answer because I answered my own question. Sorry if that is improper...

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your problem code snippet and what syntax error its giving you so we can see how you're writing your code? Its hard to answer your question without knowing those details.

Typically your PHP code for a function should look like the following:

```
<?php
function myFunction( value) {
  if (value == "true") {
    echo "Your value is true" 
     }
  else {
    echo "Your value returned false"
   }
?>
```

If that doesn't clarify, check the following article on writing PHP functions with If statements. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp